# Why doesn't my VS Code 1.77 installation on Windows with the user setup have "Check for Updates" commands / buttons?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code can't auto update to the latest version. Every time I have to update by download the latest version and reinstall it. I remember it has a check update button before. Why has it disappeared?

I have tried many times and it doesn't work.

```
版本: 1.77.3 (user setup)
提交: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
日期: 2023-04-12T09:16:02.548Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
沙盒化: No
```

In my settings.json: `"update.mode": "default"`.

Running `Code: Check for Updates...` in my command palette shows "No matching commands", and in my gear menu in the sidebar, there is no item to check for updates.

I download from the Official website. Its name is ‘VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.77.3.exe’. The previous two versions also both have the problem.

Comment: It works,I download the lastest version(VSCodeSetup-x64-1.78.2.exe, System installer) and install it. The help menu and setting button have check for update option now!

Comment: The same thing happened here, I fixed it by changing from User Installer to System Installer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be fixed for you on VS Code 1.78. I'm not sure why the checking for updates command and gear menu item weren't there for you in 1.77.

This issue ticket might be related, but the issue was reported for a user using VS Code insiders 1.78: [Check For Updates menu option missing
#180430](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/180430) (from googling "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues 1.77 check for updates`"). Another one for a 1.70 user: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178849.